# How to fix -0 issue in numpy.around()

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithm on Python, and due to the complex number manipulations involved (or maybe just due to the inherent difficulty of the computer to process floats), a lot of times I get minute deviations from the expected value.

I had to use `numpy.around` to round the result of the calculations to an acceptable precision (10 decimal places). Due to this, I sometimes end up getting numbers such as -0+0j. This might not seem like a huge problem on the surface, but the calculations which followed involved finding the arguments of the complex numbers (for the phase spectrum). Therefore, I got wrong values, since signs play a huge role in the computation.

Is there any way I can convert these -0 results to 0? A bit of the code is given below. The focus here is the return statement in the `fft(f)` function.

```py
...
def fft(f):
    Ni = len(f)
    Mi = int(Ni / 2)
    if Mi <= 2:
       return [f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[3], 
               f[0] - 1j*f[1] - f[2] + 1j*f[3],
               f[0] - f[1] + f[2] - f[3],
               f[0] + 1j*f[1] - f[2] - 1j*f[3]]

    wn = math.cos(2*math.pi/Ni) - 1j*math.sin(2*math.pi/Ni)
    fe = [f[i] for i in range(Ni) if i % 2 == 0]
    fo = [f[i] for i in range(Ni) if i % 2 == 1]
    Fe = fft(fe)
    Fo = fft(fo)
    return [np.around(Fe[i] + (wn**i)*Fo[i], decimals=10) for i in range(Mi)] + [np.around(Fe[i] - (wn**i)*Fo[i], decimals=10) for i in range(Mi)]

x = [np.around(signal(n*tp/N), decimals=10) for n in range(N)] # input sequence
_X = fft(x) # discrete Fourier transform
X = [Xi/N for Xi in _X] # frequency spectrum
X_amp = [np.absolute(Xi) for Xi in X] # amplitude spectrum
X_phase = [np.angle(Xi) for Xi in X] # phase spectrum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a general way to avoid this--negative zero is indeed just a reality of working with floating point numbers.

If you want the complex argument to be zero for the case of negative zero, then you could do something like this to replace it with "positive" zero:

```
X_phase = [np.angle(Xi if Xi else 0+0j) for Xi in X] # phase spectrum
```

This will replace all zero values regardless of sign with the value having "positive" real and imaginary parts.